# Don't have MVC 5 in VS2013, why?

Tags: model-view-controller

I want to create a C# MVC Project, so I choose ASP.NET Web Application. After I select it, there should an option to select MVC. But no. I only have Empty, WebForms and Azure Mobile Service. What about MVC? It should be there. I'm using VS2013 Ultimate Update 4. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Start by selecting "ASP.NET Web Application", click on "OK".

You'll then be presented with this dialogue:

[image]

Where you can choose to select the template you want (in this case, MVC).

Comment: Assuming you selected "everything" when installing VS.

Comment: That the options I was talking about... No MVC there

Comment: If you go into `Help -> About` under the `Installed Products` do you see the ASP.NET Web Framework & Tools 2013?